# Ruby templates: How to pass variables into inlined ERB?

Tags: ruby, templates, syntax, erb

I have an ERB template inlined into Ruby code:

```
require 'erb'

DATA = {
    :a => "HELLO",
    :b => "WORLD",
}

template = ERB.new <<-EOF
    current key is: <%= current %>
    current value is: <%= DATA[current] %>
EOF

DATA.keys.each do |current|
    result = template.result
    outputFile = File.new(current.to_s,File::CREAT|File::TRUNC|File::RDWR)
    outputFile.write(result)
    outputFile.close
end
```

I can't pass the variable "current" into the template.

The error is:

```
(erb):1: undefined local variable or method `current' for main:Object (NameError)
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it!

I create a bindings class

```
class BindMe
    def initialize(key,val)
        @key=key
        @val=val
    end
    def get_binding
        return binding()
    end
end
```

and pass an instance to ERB

```
dataHash.keys.each do |current|
    key = current.to_s
    val = dataHash[key]

    # here, I pass the bindings instance to ERB
    bindMe = BindMe.new(key,val)

    result = template.result(bindMe.get_binding)

    # unnecessary code goes here
end
```

The .erb template file looks like this:

```
Key: <%= @key %>
```

Comment: This is unnecessary. In the code from your original question, just replace "result = template.result" with "result = template.result(binding)" That will use the each block's context rather than the top-level context.

Answer (score 69):

For a simple solution, use [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/classes/OpenStruct.html):

```
require 'erb'
require 'ostruct'
namespace = OpenStruct.new(name: 'Joan', last: 'Maragall')
template = 'Name: <%= name %> <%= last %>'
result = ERB.new(template).result(namespace.instance_eval { binding })
#=> Name: Joan Maragall
```

The code above is simple enough but has (at least) two problems: 1) Since it relies on `OpenStruct`, an access to a non-existing variable returns `nil` while you'd probably prefer that it failed noisily. 2) `binding` is called within a block, that's it, in a closure, so it includes all the local variables in the scope (in fact, these variables will shadow the attributes of the struct!).

So here is another solution, more verbose but without any of these problems:

```
class Namespace
  def initialize(hash)
    hash.each do |key, value|
      singleton_class.send(:define_method, key) { value }
    end 
  end

  def get_binding
    binding
  end
end

template = 'Name: <%= name %> <%= last %>'
ns = Namespace.new(name: 'Joan', last: 'Maragall')
ERB.new(template).result(ns.get_binding)
#=> Name: Joan Maragall
```

Of course, if you are going to use this often, make sure you create a `String#erb` extension that allows you to write something like `"x=<%= x %>, y=<%= y %>".erb(x: 1, y: 2)`.

Comment: Did you test this? On my system your precise code produces "NameError: undefined local variable or method `name' for main:Object." (Edit: Appears to be a 1.9.2 issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242470/problem-using-openstruct-with-erb )

Comment: @Ryan. Indeed, I tested it only 1.8.7, updated. I'll add an answer in the question you link, I think `instance_eval` is the easiest solution. Thanks for poiting out the problem.

Comment: What does the `namespace.instance_eval { binding }` do?

Comment: I'm reading what `instance_eval` does but I just don't know what it means to execute binding in the context of `namespace`. From the docs: `Evaluates a string containing Ruby source code, or the given block, within the context of the receiver (obj). In order to set the context, the variable self is set to obj while the code is executing, giving the code access to obj’s instance variables. `

Answer (score 31):

Simple solution using [Binding](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html):

```
b = binding
b.local_variable_set(:a, 'a')
b.local_variable_set(:b, 'b')
ERB.new(template).result(b)
```

Comment: `local_variable_set` was introduces in ruby 2.1.

Answer (score 8):

In the code from original question, just replace

```
result = template.result
```

with

```
result = template.result(binding)
```

That will use the each block's context rather than the top-level context.

(Just extracted the comment by @sciurus as answer because it's the shortest and most correct one.)

Answer (score 7):

```
require 'erb'

class ERBContext
  def initialize(hash)
    hash.each_pair do |key, value|
      instance_variable_set('@' + key.to_s, value)
    end
  end

  def get_binding
    binding
  end
end

class String
  def erb(assigns={})
    ERB.new(self).result(ERBContext.new(assigns).get_binding)
  end
end
```

REF : http://stoneship.org/essays/erb-and-the-context-object/

Answer (score 4):

I can't give you a very good answer as to why this is happening because I'm not 100% sure how ERB works, but just looking at the [ERB RDocs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/erb/rdoc/classes/ERB.html#M000304), it says that you need a `binding` which is "a Binding or Proc object which is used to set the context of code evaluation".

Trying your above code again and just replacing

```
result = template.result
```

with

```
result = template.result(binding)
```

made it work.

I'm sure/hope someone will jump in here and provide a more detailed explanation of what's going on. Cheers.

EDIT: For some more information on `Binding` and making all of this a little clearer (at least for me), check out the [Binding RDoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Binding.html).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the cleanest solution would be to pass specific `current` local variable to erb template instead of passing the entire `binding`. It's possible with [ERB#result_with_hash](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#result_with_hash-method) method (introduced in Ruby 2.5)

```rb
DATA.keys.each do |current|
  result = template.result_with_hash(current: current)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As others said, to evaluate ERB with some set of variables, you need a proper binding. There are some solutions with defining classes and methods but I think simplest and giving most control and safest is to generate a clean binding and use it to parse the ERB. Here's my take on it (ruby 2.2.x):

```
module B
  def self.clean_binding
    binding
  end

  def self.binding_from_hash(**vars)
    b = self.clean_binding
    vars.each do |k, v|
      b.local_variable_set k.to_sym, v
    end
    return b
  end
end
my_nice_binding = B.binding_from_hash(a: 5, **other_opts)
result = ERB.new(template).result(my_nice_binding)
```

I think with `eval` and without `**` same can be made working with older ruby than 2.1

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This is a dirty workaround. Please see my other answer.

It's totally strange, but adding

```
current = ""
```

before the "for-each" loop fixes the problem.

*God bless scripting languages and their "language features"...*

Comment: I think this is because block parameters are not real bound variables in Ruby 1.8. This has changed in Ruby 1.9.

Comment: The default binding that ERB uses to evaluate the variables is the top level binding. Your variable "current" does not exist in the top level binding, unless you use it there first (assign a value to it).