# Binding in 1.9.2

Tags: binding, erb, ruby-1.9.2

I used to use ERB templates everywhere using the following technique:

```
def create_from_template(file, template, vars)
  contents = File.read(template(template))
  struct = OpenStruct.new(vars)
  result = ERB.new(contents).result(struct.binding)
  File.open(file, 'w') { |f| f.write result }
end
```

And I use it the following way:

```
app = App.new(...)
create_from_template('new_file', 'template', { :app => app })
```

So in my template I could have:

```
<%= app.name %>
```

And it would replace fine in REE 1.8.7, however in 1.9.2 I get the following error:

```
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `app' for #<ERB:0x007ffe6b838468>
```

**QUESTION:** How can I make this code 1.9.2 compliant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found that another question in StackOverflow addresses this issue and proposes a fix that works:

[Problem using OpenStruct with ERB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242470/problem-using-openstruct-with-erb)