# Why is JBuilder not returning a response body in JSON when testing RSPEC

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec, jbuilder

When testing a JSON response from an RSPEC controller test using DHH's JBuilder, my response.body is always "{}".  It works fine in development/production modes AND when I use the to_json method instead of jbuilder, I get proper JSON in my response.body.

Anyone have a clue as to why my response.body would always be "{}" when testing?

----- Debugger

it "should return the cart items via JSON", :focus do

get :index, :format => :json
end

(rdb:1) response.body

"{}"

Answer (score 69, accepted):

For anyone that is having the same issue. I have figured it out.

You must call `render_views` within the controller tests you are doing. If you do that, you should then see a `response.body` with your JSON contained :)

Comment: You must call `render_views` because when running controllers, view rendering is by default disabled. This speeds up the running of the test since you should only be testing controller behavior in a controller test.

Comment: how to use `render_views`, ref: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-5/docs/controller-specs/render-views

Comment: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

> Note: To encourage more isolated testing, views are not rendered by default in controller specs. If you are verifying discrete view logic, use a view spec. If you are verifying the behaviour of a controller and view together, consider a request spec. You can use `render_views` if you must verify the rendered view contents within a controller spec, but this is not recommended.

Answer (score 27):

You could find a solution from https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/32

So in rspec/spec_helper.rb

```ruby
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/32
  config.render_views = true
end
```

After above option are added, JSON result will show via jbuilder renderer

Comment: You can't put this in the `spec_helper.rb` anymore. Now you have to do this on the `rails_helper.rb`
more info: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1918
(I commented because edit queue is full)