# JBuilder returns empty response body in RSPEC integration testing

Tags: rspec, jbuilder

I know there has been a very similar question ([Why is JBuilder not returning a response body in JSON when testing RSPEC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965945/why-is-jbuilder-not-returning-a-response-body-in-json-when-testing-rspec)).
I'm testing an API endpoint that returns a JSON response generated by a JBuilder template. The response body is always empty. Some of the responders to the previous question suggested enabling **render_views** either globally or directly in the test example. From what I understand render_views only works inside controller examples, but mine is not and including render_views does not seem to be affecting anything when included globally and throws an *undefined variable* error when included directly in the example.

```
describe "GET /api/v3/shows/:id" do
  let!(:show)    { FactoryGirl.create(:show) }
  let!(:season)  { FactoryGirl.create(:season, show_id: show.id) }

  it "returns basic metadata for show" do
    get_show(show.id, valid_user_credentials(user), valid_partner_credentials(partner))

    # debugging
    # verify that show exists
    puts show.id 
    puts show.title

    puts "Response: #{response.body}"

  end
end
```

The console output:

```
dmz@miranda|tv_api:shows|$ be rspec spec/integration/api_v3/show_spec.rb
/Users/dmitry/Code/Intrn/watchitnow/spec/support/vcr.rb:9 Disabled noisy VCR missing warnings. This          
causes OAuthException 400 errors. TODO: Add OAuth VCR cassettes.
1
Item Title 1
Response:
.***
```

Has anyone had this issue? Thanks.