# How to create new binding and assign instance variables to it for availability in ERB?

Tags: ruby, erb

I'm implementing HTML templating in a Ruby project (non-rails). To do this I'll be using ERB, but I have some concerns about the binding stuff.

First out, this is the method I got so far:

```
def self.template(template, data)
  template = File.read("#{ENV.root}/app/templates/#{template}.html.erb")

  template_binding = binding.clone

  data.each do |k, v|
    template_binding.local_variable_set(k, v)
  end

  ERB.new(template).result(template_binding)
end
```

To call it I'll just do

```
Email.template('email/hello', {
  name: 'Bill',
  age:  41
}
```

There are two issues with the current solution though.

**First**, I'm cloning the current binding. I want to create a new one. I tried `Class.new.binding` to create a new, but since `binding` is a private method it can't be obtained that way.
The reason I want a new one is that I want to avoid the risk of instance variables leaking into or out from the ERB file (cloning only takes care of the latter case).

**Second**, I want the variables passed to the ERB file to be exposed as instance variables. Here I tried with `template_binding.instance_variable_set`, passing the plain hash key `k` which complained that it wasn't a valid instance variable name and `"@#{k}"`, which did not complain but also didn't get available in the ERB code.
The reason I want to use instance variables is that it's a convention that the people relying on this code is familiar with.

I have checked some topics here at Stack Overflow such as [Render an ERB template with values from a hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954706/render-an-erb-template-with-values-from-a-hash), but the answers provided does not address the problems I'm discussing.

So in short, like the title: *How to create new binding and assign instance variables to it for availability in ERB?*

Comment: I'm having a similar problem, that whenever I create a binding in Rails it has access to all my Rails ActiveRecord classes (User for example), and I don't want it to.  I want it to have the same sort of environment as a new `irb` console would.  Did you figure that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) No need to clone, new binding is created for you each time.

I have tested this in irb:

```
class A; def bind; binding; end; end
a = A.new
bind_1 = a.bind
bind_2 = a.bind

bind_1.local_variable_set(:x, 2)
=> 2
bind_1.local_variables
=> [:x]
bind_2.local_variables
=> []
```

2) Open the objects Eigenclass and add `attr_accessor` to it

```
class << template_binding  # this opens Eigenclass for object template_binding
  attr_accessor :x
end
```

So in ruby you can just open any class and add methods for it.
Eigenclass means class of a single object - each object can have custom class definition. Coming from C# I couldn't imagine a situation where this would be used, until now. :)

Do this for each hash

```
data.each do |k, v|
  class << template_binding; attr_accessor k.to_sym; end
  template_binding.k = v
end
```

Comment: Thanks Marko, that's really useful! I guess using the current binding would expose the current instance variables to the ERB code, but using something like what you do in the first line to create a dummy class from which to retrieve a new binding would fix that problem.

Comment: I don't understand your fear - that ERB code will add new instance variables to your object? That sounds impossible - try your scenario in IRB. Also upvote and accept the answer if it was helpful ;)

Comment: That was one of the fears, which I tried and, as you said, it does not seem to work that way. Also, the ERB code might get instance variables that it shouldn't. I want to be 100% explicit on what data gets passed to the ERB. Your answer helped me so I've upvoted and accepted it. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I've come to this with a different fear, which is that I want to have erb templates exposed to our admin users, to write emails, that only give them access to pre-defined variables, and basic language features like if/else, but don't have access to the wider rails env, so they can't put <% User.delete_all %> or something.

Comment: The problem I have is that however I create a new binding it always has access to the wider environment, ie all the classes defined in Rails, whereas I want it to be more basic - the same sort of binding you would get if you just opened an 'irb' console.