# How to pass and render a ruby variable in a markdown file? Gem "redcarpet"

Tags: ruby, markdown

I'm using the gem "redcarpet". And I have a markdown file. I want to be able to render it with some ruby variables. Something like this:

```
 # my_file.md

 ###Something
 fdafdsfdsfds

 ---

 <% for n in my_numbers do %>
     <%= n %>
 <% end %>
```

What's the proper way to do something like this? How can I pass and render a ruby 
variable?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `erb` library which is included in ruby, but you have to require it:

```
require 'erb'
require 'redcarpet'

input = File.read "./file.md"

markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML, autolink: true, tables: true)

output = markdown.render ERB.new(input).result(binding)

File.open("output.html", "w") { |f| f.write output }
```

You can customize the markdown renderer by referencing the [redcarpet readme](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet)

Comment: what's binding?

Comment: binding is a special variable, search google for "what is binding in ruby" for more info. The ruby variables are assumed to be in the `file.md` file ...

Comment: why use metaprogramming without necessity? how will I pass a concrete variable, not all of the context?

Comment: this isn't really much metaprogramming. If you want to only expose particular data and not the whole context, you can create a custom binding object, but i'm not really sure why you would want to do that.

Comment: `If you want to only expose particular data and not the whole context, you can create a custom binding object, ` --- how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589976/how-to-create-new-binding-and-assign-instance-variables-to-it-for-availability-i