# Generate HTML files with ERB?

Tags: html, ruby, erb

If I have an `.html.erb` file that looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= @name %>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I generate an HTML file that looks like this?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        John
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I execute the template (passing the name parameter) given that the format is .html.erb and be able to get just an .html file?

Comment: Is it what you want? 
http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/#other-resources

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
#page.html.erb
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= @name %>
    </body>
</html>
```

...

```
require 'erb'

erb_file = 'page.html.erb'
html_file = File.basename(erb_file, '.erb') #=>"page.html"

erb_str = File.read(erb_file)

@name = "John"
renderer = ERB.new(erb_str)
result = renderer.result()

File.open(html_file, 'w') do |f|
  f.write(result)
end
```

...

```
$ ruby erb_prog.rb
$ cat page.html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        John
    </body>
</html>
```

Of course, to make things more interesting, you could always change the line `@name = "John"` to:

```
print "Enter a name: "
@name = gets.chomp
```

Comment: if you need a binding to get the instance variable readable from the template, and are using Ruby 2.1+, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28006697/626369

Answer (score 0):

The ruby ERB library operates on strings, so you would have to read the .erb file into a string, create an ERB object, and then output the result into an html file, passing the current binding to the ERB.result method.

It would look something like

```
my_html_str = ERB.new(@my_erb_string).result(binding)
```

where `@my_erb_string`. You could then write the html string into an html file.

You can read more about binding [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Binding.html) and about the ERB library [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#).

Comment: I have two questions: How can I write that result into an HTML file, and how can I make sure that the binding has @name defined?

Comment: @blackghost Html is just a normal text file, so basic IO stuff still works: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777802/how-to-write-to-file-in-ruby) As for binding, the binding() method returns a binding object, which captures the environment it's called in. So if `@name` is defined in the same context that binding is called, it will be accessible in the erb.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code:

```
require 'erb'

template = File.read("template.html.erb")

renderer = ERB.new(template)

class Message
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def get_binding
    binding()
  end

end

message = Message.new 'John'

File.open('result.html', 'w') do |f|
  f.write renderer.result message.get_binding
end
```

The `template.html.erb` is your *.html.erb* template file and `result.html` is the rendered html file.

Some nice articles you can take a look, [link1](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/), [link2](http://garethrees.co.uk/2014/01/12/create-a-template-rendering-class-with-erb/).