# Sinatra - render "erb" within Module

Tags: ruby, sinatra

How can I use `erb` within a Module in Sinatra? Here is an example of a complete app, where `erb` fails within a Module.

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/yes' do
  erb "<%= Time.now %>" #works
end

get '/no' do 
  MyMod.foo #fails
end

module MyMod
  extend self

  def foo
    erb "<%= Time.now %>" #fails: undefined method `erb' for MyMod:Module
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

The `erb` method is defined in `Sinatra::Templates`. So one would think he'd be able to just use that

```
module MyMod
  extend Sinatra::Templates
  extend self

  def foo
    erb Time.now.to_s
  end
end
```

However, it's not that simple. Now `erb` method is found, but still doesn't work

> NameError at /no
>
> undefined local variable or method `settings' for MyMod:Module

If you follow that rabbit hole, you'll need to make your module a full sinatra app (don't know if that's even possible).

Why don't you use a modular sinatra app style (create a class which inherits from `Sinatra::Base`) and include your module into the app? This way I'm quite confident it'll "just work".

Comment: Yes, that's the rabbit hole I was going down into... I'll try your suggestion. But isn't there a way to use Sinatra's 'erb' with regular Sinatra modules?

Comment: There's no such thing as "regular sinatra module" :)

Comment: :) I mean, a regular Ruby module.

Comment: `erb` would happily work if you satisfied all its dependencies (like the `settings` method here) and **all their dependencies**. The easiest way is to include said module in a real sinatra app class (then you don't need to include `Sinatra::Templates`, obviously.)

Comment: Why do you even *use* a module here? I see no purpose.

Comment: To encapsulate behavior. I want an 'Emails' module to render HTML emails. Other relevant solutions for this are also appreciated. :)

BTW, have been unsuccessful with using a Sinatra app class.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the answer you are looking for.  Here is my another version. Probably this is close to what you wanted to achieve.

```
module MyMod  
  extend self

  def foo
    ERB.new("<%= Time.now %>").result   
  end
end

get '/' do
   MyMod.foo
end
```

or with helpers??

```
module Sinatra
    module MyMod  
        def foo
            erb "<%= Time.now %>"
        end
    end
    helpers MyMod
end

get '/' do
    foo
end
```

Comment: you don't need string interpolation for this.

Comment: Yes, I am specifically asking how to render *within the module* rather than returning to the main app before rendering.

Comment: I see you changed it a bit :) - this is indeed closer. I'd rather use Sinatra's own 'erb' (for compatibility); at the very least I'll need to figure out how to pass ERB.new parameters and a layout file (which is basically the main use-case for Sinatra's 'erb'..)

Comment: @sellarafaeli  re the parameters, do you mean `ERB.new("#{params['aaa']}").result` ?

Comment: @sellarafaeli also, that ERB.new line is not sinatra's own ERB.  If you start irb, and type require 'erb', then you see the ERB.new line works. And there is even a command line erb. if I do which erb, I see a /usr/local/bin/erb

Comment: @sellarafaeli and as for another way of passing to the erb, really passing to the erb, see asfer's answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338960/ruby-templates-how-to-pass-variables-into-inlined-erb

Answer (score 1):

Extending answer of @Sergio Tulentsev:
To imitate rendering behavior of Sinatra controller you can create module like this:

```
module ErbRender

  include Sinatra::Templates
  include Sinatra::Helpers
  include Sinatra::ContentFor

  def settings
    @settings ||= begin
      settings = Sinatra::Application.settings
      settings.root = "#{ROOT}/app"
      settings
    end
  end

  def template_cache
    @template_cache ||= Tilt::Cache.new
  end

end
```

*Here you may need to tune `settings.root`*

Usage example:

```
class ArticleIndexingPostBody

  include ErbRender

  def get_body
    erb :'amp/articles/show', layout: :'amp/layout'
  end

end
```

This will properly render templates with layouts including `content_for`

Answer (score 0):

Solution - call `erb` on a Sinatra::Application instance, as below (two ways of calling it, second one is preferable).

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/yes' do
  erb "<%= Time.now %>" #works
end

get '/foo' do 
  MyMod.foo #works
end

get '/foo2' do
  MyMod.foo2 #works 
end

module MyMod 
  extend self

  def foo
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Sinatra::Application).first.erb "<%= Time.now %>"
  end

  def foo2
    @app ||= Sinatra::Application.new.instance_variable_get :@instance
    @app.erb "<%= Time.now %>"
  end 
end
```