# How to attach dynamic file content in email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to attach a dynamic file in my email. I have the following code:

```
attachments["#{@company}likelist.xls"] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/views/products/like_list.xls.erb")
```

`like_list.xls.erb` is a dynamic HTML table created by iterating a variable in Ruby. I used `respond_to format.xls` to convert the `like_list.html.erb` table to XLS, however, the attachment sent is empty as no Ruby code is executed. `File.read` only reads static files.

`like_list.xls.erb` looks like this:

```
<table border="1">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th><%= t ('product_table.name')%></th>
    <th><%= t ('product_table.code')%></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @like_list.each do |key, value| %>
      <% value.each do |t| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%=t.code%></td>
          <td><%=key%></td>
...
```

Is there any way I can attach a dynamic file in Rails 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that's because you sending just a template. But you should construct a table first.

I don't know what data type is your `@like_list` is, but let's say it is a Hash.

In that case you should build your attachment. Here is just an example that shows the basic approach:

```
  # mailer
  def table_deliver
    to = "user@example.com"
    from = "no-reply@example.com"
    subject = "Foo"

    @company = "Ggl"
    @like_list = { foo: 1,
                   bar: 2,
                   baz: 3 }
    attachments["#{@company}likelist.xls"] = build_table(@like_list)
    @body = "Mail body"
    mail(to: to, from: from, subject: subject)
  end

  private

  def build_table(data)
    opts = OpenStruct.new(data)
    template = ERB.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/views/products/like_list.xls.erb"))
    template.result(opts.instance_eval { binding })
  end

# template

<table>
  <thead>
    <th>foo</th>
    <th>bar</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% data.each do |k, v| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= k %></td>
        <td><%= v %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And the result in letter_opener:

[image: email]

Attachment opened in libre office

[image: office]

Hope that helps and feel free to ask some additional questions.

**UPDATE**

First you create an [OpenStruct](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) from your Hash params. Then create a new ERB class instance.

`result` is a method of ERB class, that applies params to existing template.

`binding` is an object that provides access to the instance methods and variables that are owned by another object.

More info [here](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/)

`instance_eval` is a Object method that evaluates a string containing Ruby source code, or the given block, within the context of the receiver (obj).

More info [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval)

So, that code do the following

- creates some struct with key-value pairs
- creates new template
- executes `binding` object in context of template and assigns key-value pairs to the template.

You could refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338960/ruby-templates-how-to-pass-variables-into-inlined-erb) for more details

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you explain what `template.result(opts.instance_eval { binding })` does?